# Why its showing key error when i am using setdefault method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am using setdefault method and following this tutorial: [This tutorial](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Here a example which is :

```
my_string = 'abc'
tree = {}
def add_to_tree(root, value_string):



    for character in value_string:
        root = root.setdefault(character, {})
        print(tree['a']['b'])


add_to_tree(tree, my_string)
```

Why its showing key error when i am using setdefault ?

edit: I got the error but please explain how this code is working?

Comment: first time `tree['a'] ` return empty dict when you type `tree['a']['b']` you are trying access item with the key `b` which does not exist

Comment: then it should show default value?

Answer (score 0):

first time `tree['a']` return empty dict when you type `tree['a']['b']` you are trying access item with the key `b` which does not exist this raise error `key error` so if want to print tree with default value for keys which does not exist use `get` method it take two paramters first is the key second is the default value to return if item not exist example:

```
>>> d={}
>>> d.get('d','')
''
>>> d.get('d',0)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

`tree['a']['b']` is trying to access the value associated with `'b'` in the *empty* dictionary `tree['a']`. Your code doesn't populate any dictionaries it creates in `root`.